# Add thousand separator and dollar sign to DataGrid column WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to add Dollar sign and Thousand separator to a datagrid column in WPF. I'm using like this.

```
<s:String x:Key="formatDoller">{0:C}</s:String>
```

When I use like this both thousand seperater and the doller sign is showing.
For example :

```
5689 showing as $5,689.00
```

But here I need to remove last two decimal points. I need to show

```
     5689 as $5,689
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead to remove the 00 at the end of the number

```
<s:String x:Key="formatDoller">{0:C0}</s:String>
```